# Error saving CKRecord and CKShare in CKModifyRecordsOperation

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I'm trying to save a CKRecord (already created and saved to the database) and a new CKShare to it but I keep getting this error: *Optional("Failed to modify some records")*. Here is my code:

```
    let csc = UICloudSharingController { controller, preparationCompletionHandler in

        let share = CKShare(rootRecord: user)
        share[CKShareTitleKey] = "My Share" as CKRecordValue
        share.publicPermission = .readWrite

        let mro = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [user, share], recordIDsToDelete: nil)

        mro.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
        mro.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10

        mro.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { records, recordIDs, error in
            if error != nil {
                print("ERROR IN MODIFY RECORDS COMPLETION BLOCK\n")
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
            preparationCompletionHandler(share,CKContainer.default(), error)
        }
        privateData.add(mro)
    }
    csc.availablePermissions = [.allowPrivate,.allowReadWrite]
    self.present(csc, animated:true)
}
```

The problem is in this method: *modifyRecordsCompletionBlock*. Can somebody explain me why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it

All you have to do is create a private custom CKZone and save your CKRecord and CKShare in it, you cannot use the default zone cloud kit gives to you!

Comment: Can you update your answer indicate if you did this via code or in CloudKit dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

To leave a shared record, you have to delete the CKShare record from the *shared* database otherwise you'll get errors.